# Can a mixed state be a stationary state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, density-operator

If we define a stationary state as a state in which the probability distributions for every observable are constant in time, is it fair to say that a mixed state can also be a stationary state? One usually sees the particular case of a pure state (in which case we need a Hamiltonian eigenstate). However, I think that if we have a (incoherent) mixture of such eigenstates $\rho = \sum_n p_n |E_n\rangle \langle E_n|$ then the trace Born rule should also show that all probability distributions associated with this (mixed) state are time independent too. I'm not sure about this though.

Thus my questions are (1) is my definition of a stationary state correct and (2) can a mixed state therefore be a stationary state?

Comment: Stationary states are solutions of Schrodinger equation.

Comment: Have you inspected your non Neumann equation? What have you concluded?

Comment: I know of it. I suppose it supports my assertion (that if every projector in the density operator is built up of Hamiltonian eigenkets then we have a density operator that remains unchanged in time). I think I see now but am hoping you or someone else can confirm that's correct. @CosmasZachos

Comment: Trust your calculation.

Comment: System in thermodynamic equilibrium is a good example.

Comment: @RogerVadim That being because it is precisely of the convex sum of Hamiltonian eigenket projectors form? I will add this example into my notes, thank you.

Comment: A simpler way of saying it: it commutes with the Hamiltonian.

Comment: Noted! Thanks. @RogerVadim